# Determining the Cartesian equation of a plane....

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> A plane, $\Pi$, has $3x-5z+3=0$ as its Cartesian equation. Determine the Cartesian equation of a plane that is perpendicular to $\Pi$ and contains the point $P(2,9,-3)$

Does anyone know how to solve this

Comment: Hint: two planes are considered perpendicular if their normals are perpendicular.

Comment: Have you done any work on the problem so far? Showing what you've done and know already will make helping you more effective

Comment: make the ansatz $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it must be $$[a,b,c]\cdot [3,0,-5]=0$$ and $$2a+9b-3c+d=0$$